# TCustomControl Cursor refresh

Tags: delphi

I have a TCustomControl that zoom's an image. When zooming in the controls cursor is set to crZoomIn (+) and when zooming out the controls cursor is set to crZoomOut (-).

When testing, **the controls cursor is set correctly**, but the cursor does not refresh itself **until the mouse is moved out of the control and then back onto the control**.

How can I refresh or update the cursor without having to move the mouse out of the control then back onto the control?

{EDIT]

The code to change the cursor is:

```
procedure TBitmapEditor.ZoomIn;
begin
  if Magnification = 1 then
    Magnification := 2
  else if Magnification < 32 then
    Magnification := Magnification + 2;
  Cursor := crZoomIn;
  Perform( CM_CURSORCHANGED, 0, 0 );
end;

procedure TBitmapEditor.ZoomOut;
begin
  if Magnification = 2 then
    Magnification := 1
  else if Magnification > 1 then
    Magnification := Magnification - 2;
  Cursor := crZoomOut;
  Perform( CM_CURSORCHANGED, 0, 0 );
end;
```

Perform( CM_CURSORCHANGED, 0, 0 ); does not change the cursor, but the cursor is set correctly I think because when I move the mouse as described the cursor changes correctly.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Some minimal code, perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried `Perform(CM_CURSORCHANGED, 0, 0)`?

Comment: I changed it to: 
  Cursor := crZoomOut;
  Windows.SetCursor( Screen.Cursors[ crZoomOut ] );
  Perform( CM_CURSORCHANGED, 0, 0 );

Now it works as expected.  Thanks Andreas...

Comment: @Bill: But `SetCursor` affects your entire application, not only the custom control. It is the same thing as `Screen.Cursor`,  I think.

Comment: yep I think you are right.... unfortunately nothing else seems to work.  oh Dear.

Comment: What else are you doing when zooming? SetCursor, just as moving the cursor out and in of the control, goes through the Windows API. I may be way off base, but the fact that the cursor does change when you use those, leads me to believe that you are not giving your app a chance to process windows messages to repaint the cursor. You could confirm this by sticking a `application.processmessages` in your zooiming code, though I would not recommend that as the final solution.